# VBA code to find and replace double quotes in .xls in notepad

Tags: excel, vba, notepad

I need to replace double quotes in .xls SAP export file in notepad to be able to load it into excel and do other steps.

The problem with .xls is that some double quotes are not finished and it causes the file to concatenate multiple rowsinto in when opening in excel

[image: Not finished double quotes]

I tried it simply through load into powerquery, transform into columns, replace double quotes, but the result is not satisfying as it concatenate 4 columns of one line into one cell

[image: removed double quotes]

So this partially worked, but the most succesful step is to open xls in notepad and Replace " with nothing. This works manually, but when doing it through VBA it just removes 3/4 of the data from 450 000 lines I have 160 000.

I am using following code

```
Sub changeDQ()
Dim objFSO
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objTS
Dim strContents As String
Dim fileSpec As String
Dim DQ As String


fileSpec = "C:\31_12_2022.xls"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForReading)

strContents = objTS.ReadAll
strContents = Replace(strContents, Chr(34), " ")

objTS.Close

Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForWriting)

objTS.Write strContents
objTS.Close
End Sub
```

Is there any way to remove double quotes from the file before loading it into excel and not damaging column delimiter structure as in power query?

We are not able to change these inputs in SAP as these are closed cases

==========================
suggestions from comments:
modify `strContents = Replace(strContents, Chr(34), "")`

I tried multiple versions:

```
strContents = Replace(strContents, Chr(34), "")

strContents = Replace(strContents, Chr(34), "rplc")

strContents = Replace(strContents, """, "")

strContents = Replace(strContents, """", "")

Dim DQ as string
DQ = Chr(34)
strContents = Replace(strContents, DQ, "")
```

Result was always the same

Comment: Tryed `strContents = Replace(strContents, Chr(34), "")` empty sting?

Comment: yes, the result is the same, I tried also other versions, but with no luck, will edit main post to reflect this

Comment: Use [Textpad](https://www.textpad.com/home) to do this manually, and you will learn what the characters are in your file and then you can use `chr$(nn)` in VBA

Comment: Isn't it impossible that the characters looking as double quotes to be something else than `Chr(34`? Try selecting a cell starting with the respective character and use `Debug.print AscW(left(ActiveCell.value,1))`. What does it return in Immediate Window? Maybe two simple quotes...? `Chr(39)`... or a different one.

Comment: Not able to download Textpad, but in VS Code using extension Unicode Code Point, it is U+0022, decimal value 34, HEX 0x22 , described as QUOTATION MARK

Comment: might sound dumb, but are you sure you are saving the edited file in the same folder and name as you read later?

Comment: What do you mean by "it just removes 3/4 of the data from 450 000 lines I have 160 000." ? what is the total file size. In my past experience SAP "xls" files were tab delimited text files.

Comment: @Horaciux yes, I have the saved file

Comment: @CDP1802 original file has 450k lines, total file size is the same, I scrolled through the export and there are some mixed characters (non-latin) in the middle twice, according to notepad, there is new GL account header, so it might mixed something up, but i am still missing first 300k lines (ca).

Comment: I meant what is the SAP file size in MBytes or GBytes ?

Comment: its 54938kB before code and 54938kB after code, don't get it

Answer (score 0):

Try processing the lines separately.

```vb
Sub changeDQ()

    Const ForReading = 1
    Const ForWriting = 2
    Const fileSpec = "31_12_2022.xls"

    Dim fso, tsIn, tsOut, s As String, n As Long
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set tsIn = fso.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForReading, Format:=-2)
    Set tsOut = fso.OpenTextFile("~" & fileSpec, ForWriting, _
                Create:=True, Format:=-2) ' -2=system default -1=Unicode
    
    Do While tsIn.AtEndOfStream = False
        s = tsIn.ReadLine
        tsOut.WriteLine Replace(s, Chr(34), "")
        n = n + 1
    Loop
    tsIn.Close
    tsOut.Close
    MsgBox n & " lines processed from " & fileSpec, _
           vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
   
End Sub
```

Analyse the file with this script in a new clean workbook. Enter 100 for number of bytes and select file with dialog.

```vb
Sub CheckFile()

    Dim BYTES As Long, filename As String
    
    BYTES = InputBox("Number of bytes", "Bytes")
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        filename = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    Dim objStreamIn, i, v
    Set objStreamIn = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With objStreamIn
        .Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile filename
        .Position = 0
        v = .Read(BYTES)
    End With
    
    With Sheet1
        .Cells.Clear
        .Range("A1:D1") = Array("Pos", "Dec", "Hex", "Chr")
        For i = 2 To BYTES + 1
            .Cells(i, 1) = i - 1
            .Cells(i, 2) = CLng(v(i - 2))
            .Cells(i, 3) = Hex(v(i - 2))
            .Cells(i, 4) = ChrW(v(i - 2))
        Next
    End With
    
    MsgBox BYTES & " bytes read to sheet1 from " & filename

End Sub
```

Try this to further analyse the file.

```vb
Sub AnalyseFile()
   
    Dim a() As Byte, i As Long, n As Long, filename As String
    Dim s As String, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        filename = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
         .Open
         .Type = 1  ' adTypeBinary
         .LoadFromFile filename
         a = .Read
         .Close
    End With
   
    For i = 0 To UBound(a)
        If a(i) = 34 Then
           n = n + 1
           a(i) = 32
        End If
    Next
    s = filename & vbLf & Format(n, "#,###") & " ""'s found and replaced in  " & _
        Format(i, "#,### bytes")
    MsgBox s, vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
    
    Dim newfile
    newfile = "test_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd_hhmmss") & ".xls"
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
         .Open
         .Type = 1  ' adTypeBinary
         .Write a
         .SaveToFile newfile
         .Close
    End With
    MsgBox "new file created: " & newfile
  
End Sub
```

Comment: This process 1 line and deletes all data from the file, only three cells remains in the document and file size is 1kB

Comment: @zmk If you right click on file what size in bytes is in the properties ? Are you on Windows or Mac ? Try with Format:=-1 in `fso.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForReading, Format:=-1)`. What is the last few character in the 3rd cell ?

Comment: original file 56 255 896 bytes; third cell last character is letter P (U+0050); after code above the file size is 65 bytes; after my code the file size is 56 255 006 bytes; Win 10, Office 365 version 2208 build 15601.20456; changin format to -1 is no help

Comment: @zmk I have added a script to my answer to read the first 100 bytes. Run it for your file and see what the 66th character is.

Comment: wow, the file (xls) opened in excel looked ok, opened in vscode it is very messy, 66th character is <START OF TEXT> U+0022; it is quotation mark

Comment: @zmk Interesting, what are the 1st,2nd,3rd, 67th, and 68th character codes on the sheet1

Comment: First and second are replacement characters U+FFFD, third is Device control one U+0011, 67th and 68th is null U+0000

Comment: @zmk That looks a lot like a binary file. When you open it in notepad does it look like a plain text file, no "odd" characters ? If it is a binary file I can't help.

Comment: original file opened in notepad i see only text, with a lot of spaces, no special characters, file processed with your second code is full of special characters

Comment: @zmk OK last try, I have added another macro to my answer AnalyseFile. See if that works.

Comment: It found 408 double quote characters and made the file binary according to vscode, excel won't open it either, in Notepad++ it is a mess with a lot of different characters, ok I believe this cannot be done on this file, thank you for your support

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252258/discussion-between-cdp1802-and-zmk).